# How to solve Unsupported driver [mongodb]?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, dll, laravel-5.3

I use xampp 32 bit PHP 7.1.1

I had install mongodb 3.4.2 on my windows (windows 8 pro 64 bit)

And I also had install the driver (php_mongodb.dll)

I get from here : https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.2.5/windows (7.1 Thread Safe (TS) x86)

But, when my system executed, there still exist error :

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> 1/1 InvalidArgumentException in ConnectionFactory.php line 278:
>   Unsupported driver [mongodb] in ConnectionFactory.php line 278 at
>   ConnectionFactory->createConnection('mongodb', object(Closure),
>   'myappdb', '', array('driver' => 'mongodb', 'host' => '127.0.0.1',
>   'port' => '27017', 'database' => 'myappdb', 'username' => '',
>   'password' => '', 'options' => array('database' => 'admin'), 'prefix'
>   => '', 'name' => 'mongodb')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 64 at ConnectionFactory->createSingleConnection(array('driver' => 'mongodb',
>   'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => '27017', 'database' => 'myappdb',
>   'username' => '', 'password' => '', 'options' => array('database' =>
>   'admin'), 'prefix' => '', 'name' => 'mongodb')) in
>   ConnectionFactory.php line 50 at
>   ConnectionFactory->make(array('driver' => 'mongodb', 'host' =>
>   '127.0.0.1', 'port' => '27017', 'database' => 'myappdb', 'username' =>
>   '', 'password' => '', 'options' => array('database' => 'admin'),
>   'prefix' => '', 'name' => 'mongodb'), 'mongodb') in
>   DatabaseManager.php line 176 at
>   DatabaseManager->makeConnection('mongodb') in DatabaseManager.php line
>   68 at DatabaseManager->connection('mongodb') in Model.php line 3351 at
>   Model::resolveConnection('mongodb') in Model.php line 3317 at
>   Model->getConnection() in Model.php line 395 at
>   Model->newBaseQueryBuilder() in Model.php line 1834 at
>   Model->newQueryWithoutScopes() in Model.php line 1450 at Model->save()
>   in ReviewController.php line 31 at ReviewController->index() at
>   call_user_func_array(array(object(ReviewController), 'index'),
>   array()) in Controller.php line 55 at Controller->callAction('index',
>   array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44 at
>   ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route),
>   object(ReviewController), 'index') in Route.php line 189 at
>   Route->runController() in Route.php line 144 at
>   Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 653 at
>   Router->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php
>   line 53 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   SubstituteBindings.php line 41 at
>   SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 137 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 33 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Authenticate.php line 43 at Authenticate->handle(object(Request),
>   object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 33 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65 at
>   VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 137 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 33 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49 at
>   ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 137 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 33 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   StartSession.php line 64 at StartSession->handle(object(Request),
>   object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 33 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37 at
>   AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>   in Pipeline.php line 137 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 33 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   EncryptCookies.php line 59 at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request),
>   object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 33 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 104 at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php
>   line 655 at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route),
>   object(Request)) in Router.php line 629 at
>   Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607 at
>   Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268 at
>   Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 53 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Debugbar.php line 51 at Debugbar->handle(object(Request),
>   object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 33 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46 at
>   CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 137 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 33 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   Pipeline.php line 104 at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php
>   line 150 at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in
>   Kernel.php line 117 at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php
>   line 53

I seem to have installed the driver correctly, but why is there still exist error

How can I solve it?

Comment: Just guessing, but your driver is x86 != x64 like your mongodb?

Comment: @Myonara, I use driver 32 bit, because my version xampp is 32 bit. It should be the same. My mongodb support 32 bit & 64 bit. Look at this : https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community

Answer (score 0):

I think Laravel is looking for a database driver, not the PHP driver. Ensure that you've got a PHP package installed that will bridge a database connection for MongoDB and that it is configured correctly.

Comment: I change to xampp 32 bit PHP 7.0.8, it works. There seems to be a problem with xampp 32 bit PHP 7.1.1